# Comments to flagged posts on G+ badminton community

Tags: google-plus

Recently, I became a moderator for the **[largest badminton community on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/1/communities/102777740187839734038)**, mainly to remove spam and/or to respond to flagged posts, see pic:
[image]

In order for me to apply some sort of a "three strikes out" principle, I need to inform people.

Will this comment be seen by the person who posted this:
[image]

Comment: They should, but then again, they know what they're doing on the first post, so three strikes is a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is visible to the original poster. If they see it is an entirely different story. It will depend on if they have notifications enabled for comments on their own posts and if they actually look at the post.